# SGID on folder does not affect files

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, group

I have set sgid on a folder with user **dgillman** (me) and group **voice**. When I `touch` a new file it has my group, dgillman, instead of inheriting the group of the folder, voice. I can't find any exceptions to the expected behavior of sgid in the documentation or online. Any ideas?

I'm using bash on Ubuntu 18.04.

Following the example on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#SGID):

```
$ rm tmp
$ stat -c "%U:%G %A %n" .
dgillman:voice drwxrwsr-x .
$ echo 'NEW FILE' > tmp
$ stat -c "%U:%G %A %n" tmp
dgillman:dgillman -rw-rw-r-- tmp
```

**Updates**

1. This is happening on a mounted filesystem **Bar**. The problem does not occur in my home directory:

```
$ cd
~$ mkdir foo
~$ chmod g+s foo
~$ cd foo
dgillman:dgillman drwxrwsr-x .
~/foo$ chown dgillman.voice .
~/foo$ stat -c "%U:%G %A %n" .
dgillman:voice drwxrwsr-x .
~/foo$ touch tmp
~/foo$ stat -c "%U:%G %A %n" tmp
dgillman:voice -rw-rw-r-- tmp
```

```
$ df -Th
Filesystem               Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3                ext4       37G   33G  2.7G  93% /home
192.168.x.x:/Bar         nfs4       11T  8.0T  3.0T  74% /Bar
```

2. This [RedHat issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=623054) suggests it could be a problem on the NFS server.

**Resolution -- Not!**

My IT guy found [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f59288ff-80f9-46e2-aff6-daa232f83e08/new-files-and-folders-on-a-linux-client-mounting-a-windows-2012-server-for-nfs-share-do-not-inherit?forum=winserverfiles), which explains that the Windows 2012 NFS server has a known issue that Microsoft won't fix.

Comment: Could you please amend the `stat` command to be `stat -c "%U:%G %A %n"` and edit the results into the question so that it is possible to verify the permission settings?

Comment: @KevinO: Done, thanks.